# Segmentation fault: 11 in C when two dimension array's width > length

Tags: c

I write some code in `C`

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int width=3,height=6;
//if width>height, the programe will crash

void test(int ** input){
    printf("test value:\n\n");
    for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
            printf("%dx%d=%d\t",i,j,input[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int **p = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*width); //for rows
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)  
    {  
        *(p+i) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*height);//for cols  
    }  
    for(int i =0;i<width;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<height;j++)
            p[i][j]=i*j;

    test(p);
    return 0;
}
```

run it: 
`gcc test.c && a.out`
Nothing is wrong, everything is OK.
But, if i change `width=7` at line 4. The code will crash:

`Segmentation fault: 11`

### Why?

I run it in:

```
zenith@zenithdeMacBook-Air:/ramdisk$ uname -a
Darwin bogon 13.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
zenith@zenithdeMacBook-Air:/ramdisk$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 4):

In `main`, the line `for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)` should be `for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)`.

Your array consists of `width` number of pointers, each of which points to the first element of an array of length `height`.  (This is the opposite way around from the usual English meaning of those words, BTW).

The program works anyway if `width <= height` because you allocated enough space; but when `width > height` you do an out-of-bounds access with `*(p+i)` when `i` gets big enough.

NB. You can replace `*(p+i)` with the more readable `p[i]`, and [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).